# Some forms shown a blank in a designer codenaone

Tags: codenameone

We have finished our app and tested from QA Team and its published in app store & google play from 3 months ago, but now we need to update and add some feature in some form, all forms its opened in the designer but the problem one form show me as a blank and we can not redesign the form again. we update codeanameone before open the netbeans code, please help, as you can see the image as below

the Form is blank and there is a capital C beside it, and all opened form is F:

[image: capital]

Answer (score 1):

check whether XML TEAM MODE  is checked or unchecked . If it is checked then uncheck it or if it is unchecked then check it and close the theme designer without clicking save button . And reopen the designer then it should displays its components.[image]

Comment: Also run the designer from the [command line](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-designer-command-line-options.html) and see if there are exceptions when you try to do that. Update your post and comment here if there are